# A problem configuring webpack, coffeescript, mocha and mochapack

Tags: webpack, coffeescript, mocha.js

I have a project which uses coffeescript, webpack, mocha and mochapack.

When I import an es6 module into a coffeescript source file my tests explode.

The problem is about getting the es6 module to load correctly and not be treated as a legacy es5 file.

I have reduced the problem down to what I hope is the simplest possible demo in [this example project](https://github.com/tonyxyz/coffee_es_webpack_mocha).

This is the exact error:

```
RUNTIME EXCEPTION  Exception occurred while loading your tests
 /Users/someone/workpath/coffee_es_webpack_mocha/node_modules/animejs/lib/anime.es.js:1280
export default anime;

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at ...
```

Answer (score 1):

An old colleague pointed out I don't really need

```
externals: [nodeExternals()],
```

in the test configuration.  Removing it makes the problem go away.